# Azure Diagnostics not saving performance counters

Tags: php, azure

I have enabled Diagnostics in my Azure PHP Web Role. It seems to be indeed enabled as it's creating two tables `WADDiagnosticInfraestructureLogsTable` and `WADWindowsEventsLogTable`, as well as dumping the config in the blob container `wad-control-container`.

But it's not creating tables for the other two sections (`PerformanceCounters` and `Logs`) of my `diagnostics.wadcfg`. What am I doing wrong?

This is my `diagnostics.wadcfg`:

```
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration" configurationChangePollInterval="PT1M" overallQuotaInMB="4096">

    <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" />

    <Logs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" />

    <WindowsEventLog bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
        <DataSource name="Application!*"/>
        <DataSource name="System!*"/>
    </WindowsEventLog>

    <PerformanceCounters bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT2M">
        <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT1M"/>
        <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT1M"/>
        <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Sent/sec" sampleRate="PT1M"/>
        <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec" sampleRate="PT1M"/>
    </PerformanceCounters>

</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

This is the configuration file that Azure Diagnostics dumps into my blob storage:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <DataSources>
        <OverallQuotaInMB>4096</OverallQuotaInMB>
        <Logs>
            <BufferQuotaInMB>1024</BufferQuotaInMB>
            <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>1</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
            <ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>Verbose</ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>
        </Logs>
        <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs>
            <BufferQuotaInMB>1024</BufferQuotaInMB>
            <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>1</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
            <ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>Verbose</ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>
        </DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs>
        <PerformanceCounters>
            <BufferQuotaInMB>1024</BufferQuotaInMB>
            <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>2</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
            <Subscriptions>
                <PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
                    <CounterSpecifier>\Memory\Available MBytes</CounterSpecifier>
                    <SampleRateInSeconds>60</SampleRateInSeconds>
                </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
                <PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
                    <CounterSpecifier>\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time</CounterSpecifier>
                    <SampleRateInSeconds>60</SampleRateInSeconds>
                </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
                <PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
                    <CounterSpecifier>\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Sent/sec</CounterSpecifier>
                    <SampleRateInSeconds>60</SampleRateInSeconds>
                </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
                <PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
                    <CounterSpecifier>\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec</CounterSpecifier>
                    <SampleRateInSeconds>60</SampleRateInSeconds>
                </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
            </Subscriptions>
        </PerformanceCounters>
        <WindowsEventLog>
            <BufferQuotaInMB>1024</BufferQuotaInMB>
            <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>1</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
            <Subscriptions>
                <string>Application!*</string>
                <string>System!*</string>
            </Subscriptions>
            <ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>Verbose</ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>
        </WindowsEventLog>
        <Directories>
            <BufferQuotaInMB>0</BufferQuotaInMB>
            <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>0</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
            <Subscriptions />
        </Directories>
    </DataSources>
    <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
  </ConfigRequest>
```

In my `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` I have this:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
    <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="[myconnectionstring]"/>
    [...]
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

And in my `ServiceDefinition.csdef`:

```
<Imports>
    <Import moduleName="Diagnostics"/>
</Imports>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks good.

Did you give the deployment at least 5-10 minutes to start creating the tables and start logging?

Comment: You're right, the configuration was ok. It turned out to be failing in DevFabric only (and I think I know why: http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2011/06/mystery_of_the_windows_azure_d.html), it works as a charm on the cloud.